# Show data in angular component got from BehaviorSubject before page renders

Tags: angular, observable, lifecycle

I have tried to find solution online, but nothing worked. I get some data from the back once I login. I made a service which sends data from login component.ts file to my home page, activated on button submit event. Page renders Object[Object]. Data is sent back when I pressed login, but issue is when I get to home page, I can't find a way for data to be loaded there before page renders.

Here is my login.ts file which receives data from reactive form, and this all works.

```
onSubmit() {
    let tempUser = this.loginForm.value;
    this.user.email = tempUser.email;
    this.user.password = tempUser.password;

    this.userService.loginUser(this.user).subscribe(data=>{
      if (data.status !== 0) {
        console.log("Greska");
      }
      else {
        this.dataService.setData(data);
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      }
    })
  }
```

Here is my data.service which transfers data.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn:"root"
})
export class DataService {
  private data$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
  dataDif$ = this.data$.asObservable();

  constructor() {}

  setData(data: any) {
    this.data$.next(data);
  }
}
```

And here is my home.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

constructor (private dataService: DataService) {}
userData: UserModel = new UserModel;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.dataDif$.subscribe((data) => {
        this.userData = data;

        console.log(data)
      });
  }
```

And my home.component.html.

```
<h1>{{userData.ime}} {{userData.prezime}} je pristupio aplikaciji!</h1>
```

Comment: Try to add in your `home.component.html` this `{{userData | json}}` what gets rendered?

Comment: @robert ```{ "status": 0, "data": { "id": 1, "ime": "Boban", "prezime": "Banjevic", "email": "bobanxzcbanjevic@t-me.com" } }```

Comment: then modify the HTML to this: `<h1>{{userData.data.ime}} {{userData.data.prezime}} je pristupio aplikaciji!</h1>` if you want to keep the HTML as is then modify the assignment to this `this.userData = data.data;`

Comment: @robert in ts i added ```this.userData = data.data;``` Tnx man u saved me, i didn't know about this pipe, this is so good for debugging.